# How to get group with maximum number of equal values in two other columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
     Session                          initial final 
5a2572b8-c7bc-4e53-8731-266764fa4285    10     10
5a2572b8-c7bc-4e53-8731-266764fa4286    10     10
5a2572b8-c7bc-4e53-8731-266764fa4287    10     10
5a2572b8-c7bc-4e53-8731-266764fa4288    10     10
5a2572b8-c7bc-4e53-8731-266764fa4288    13     14
5a2572b8-c7bc-4e53-8731-266764fa4288    10     10
5a2572b8-c7bc-4e53-8731-266764fa4289    10     10
5a2572b8-c7bc-4e53-8731-266764fa4289    11     10
5a2572b8-c7bc-4e53-8731-266764fa4210    14     14
5a2572b8-c7bc-4e53-8731-266764fa4210    11     10
```

i have above table (test) in SQL, i need to calculate the session that having the max number of matching where initail = final, and vise versa

Comment: -1. Please improve question title; and show what you have tried to solve this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "vice versa" in this situation.

Comment: i mean in vise versa, that also i need the max number of session where inital dose not  equal final value as well

Comment: So you want the session with the maximum number of matches plus the one with the maximum number of mismatches?

Comment: @osama_1989: have you tried my solution at all? Note that i've edited it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes actually i tried your solution , but its return same value to me in both cases :/

Comment: @osama_1989: No, it does not: [SumSame](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d310/4/0) and [SumNotSame](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d310/3/0). You can include all columns to see what happens. I don't know what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common-table-expression with an [`OVER` clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Session, initial, final,
     Sum = SUM(CASE WHEN initial=final THEN 1 END) Over (Partition By Session)
  FROM dbo.Test
)
SELECT TOP 1 Session FROM CTE ORDER BY SUM DESC
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d310/2/0)</kbd>

I assume that "vice-versa" mean the opposite order. Then you just have to use `ORDER BY SUM ASC`. If you instead want to order by unequal initial-final values(as commented above) you can use this query:

```
WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT 
     Session, initial, final,
     SumSame    = SUM(CASE WHEN initial=final  THEN 1 END) Over (Partition By Session),
     SumNotSame = SUM(CASE WHEN initial<>final THEN 1 END) Over (Partition By Session)
  FROM dbo.Test
)
SELECT TOP 1 Session
FROM CTE
ORDER BY SumSame DESC
```

Now you can change it to `ORDER BY SumNotSame DESC` to get the max-unequal session.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d310/4/0)</kbd>

Comment: its return the same value ,either if ordered by sumsame or sumnotsame

Comment: No, it does not: [SumSame](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d310/4/0) and [SumNotSame](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d310/3/0). You can include all columns to see what happens.

Comment: more explanation please

Comment: @osama_1989: what don't you understand?

Comment: you code was helpful, but what do u mean by including all columns,

Comment: that if session number one having the max number of matching between inital and final then i need to display that session

Comment: @osama_1989: i just mentioned that you can include all columns of your table and the computed columns if you want. Just to demonstrate that the correct records are selected. If you use `GROUP BY Session` you cannot include all columns if you don't include them in the `GROUP BY` or use an aggregate function like `MIN`.

Comment: @osama_1989: i don't understand your last comment, sorry. In what way is that different to your initial requirement or the result of my query?

Comment: okay , its like 1 to many , 1 is the session and many "matching= initail and final ", that if specific session having alot of matching rather than other, i need to know it, cuz on session can have many result

Comment: @osama_1989: i still don't understand, my query always returns only one record even if there are multiple records with this session and the same inital=final value. If you want to know the count use the columns `SumSame` / `SumNotSame`.

Comment: @osama_1989: i'm glad that i could help. Consider to accept an answer then.

Comment: its worked by execute the query without the order by @Tim Schmelter

Comment: @osama_1989: without an `ORDER BY` the record you get is unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

To get the session with the maximum number of matches is easy. Just select all matches, group by session and take the top record. Same for mismatches. Here they are combined:

```
select 
  match.session as match_session,
  match.cnt as match_count,
  mismatch.session as mismatch_session,
  mismatch.cnt as mismatch_count
from
(
  select top(1) session, count(*) as cnt
  from sessions
  where initial = final
  group by session
  order by session desc
) match
cross join
(
  select top(1) session, count(*) as cnt
  from sessions
  where initial != final
  group by session
  order by session desc
) mismatch;
```